# ConEmu output getting cut off after 32 lines

Tags: conemu

Despite ConEmu's default "Console Buffer Height" setting of 1000 lines, the output from an executed program is getting cut off after only 32 lines. Am I misunderstanding this feature? My expectation was that I could scroll through up to 1000 lines of output.

Comment: Your problem is unclear.

Comment: I'm running a program that generates 1000+ lines of output. But when I scroll up to peruse it, the buffer ends at 32 lines.

Comment: Without screenshots before and after I can't tell you anything.